# How to get the value of a select form in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my first week of PHP (so no bullying). I'm trying to grab the value of a select form and insert into my db. The insert is all good but I can't seem to pass the value.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //add to top 10
    function addTop10()
    {
    var show_id = $('#show_id').val();  
    var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
    var rank = $('select.rank').val();
        //Storing the value of textbox into a variable
    if(show_id == '')        //Checking for NULL
    {
    $('#propspectDiv').html('Enter A Valid Name');    //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
    $('#show_id').addClass('error');                    //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
    return;
    }
    else{
    $('#show_id').removeClass('error');
    $('#propspectDiv').removeClass('error'); //Removing the error class from the progress DIV
    $('#propspectDiv').html('Submitting your Request.<img src="ajax.gif" />');//Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV

    $.ajax({
    url : 'top10ajax.php', //Declaration of file, in which we will send the data
    data:{
    "show_id" : show_id,  
    "user_id" : user_id,
    "rank" : rank          //we are passing the name value in URL
    },
    success : function(data){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#propspectDiv').html('Added'); //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
    }, 2000);
    }
    });
    }
    }

    </script>
```

and the html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
<h4>Add to your top 10 </h4>
<div class="two columns">
    <form>
<select name="rank">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>

</select>
</div>
<div class="four columns">
         <button class="large button" id="rank" type="button" value="Add to Top 10" onclick="addTop10()"></form>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong, besides bad formatting?

Comment: I see you mention the formatting issue - in general, it's a good idea to fix that prior to posting, in order to make your code easier to read.

Comment: I've assumed `$` is the jQuery object, and have retagged your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select.rank` will select an element of type `select` that is a member of the `rank` class.

`<select name="rank">` isn't a member of any classes. It has no class attribute.

You need to either alter your selector so it matches the element or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get value of select box in a wrong way try this instead

```
var rank = $("select['name=rank']").val();
```